# How to install Windows Service with WIX Installer with Login, and reinstall executable without credentials

Tags: wix, windows-installer

We're attempting to create an installer that installs the service with Login credentials initially, and on upgraded versions have the ability to check to see that the service is installed and then stop the service, install the upgraded exe, start the service.  The goal is to not have to keep providing credentials for reinstalling the service.

```
            <Component Id="MY_EXE" Guid="<GUID>" Win64="yes">
              <Condition>NOT SERVICEEXISTS</Condition>
              <File Id="ApplicationID" Name="my.exe" DiskId="1" Source="my.exe" KeyPath="yes" />
              <ServiceControl Id="ServiceControl" Name="MyService" Stop="both" Start="install" Remove="uninstall" Wait="yes" />
            </Component>

            <Component Id="SERVICE_USER" Guid="<GUID>" Win64="yes">
             <Condition>SERVICEEXISTS</Condition>
              <File Id="ApplicationID" Name="my.exe" DiskId="1" Source="my.exe" KeyPath="yes" />
              <ServiceInstall Id="ServiceInstaller" Name="MyService" Type="ownProcess" Vital="yes" DisplayName="My Service" Description="My Service" Start="auto" Account="[SERVICEACCOUNT]" Password="[SERVICEPASSWORD]" ErrorControl="normal" Interactive="no">
                <util:ServiceConfig FirstFailureActionType="restart" SecondFailureActionType="restart" ThirdFailureActionType="restart" ResetPeriodInDays="1" RestartServiceDelayInSeconds="30" />
              </ServiceInstall>
              <ServiceControl Id="ServiceControl" Name="MyService" Stop="both" Start="install" Remove="uninstall" Wait="yes" />
            </Component>
```

With varying attempts I can get the service installed correctly, however on subsequent upgrades the service uninstalls when component MY_EXE is installed.  My guess is that a subsequent install understands that SERVICE_USER component is not installed and triggers the uninstall of the service.

Answer (score 1):

MSI doesn't handle this very well.  About the best you can do is redefine the DeleteServices and InstallServices standard actions in the InstallExecuteSequence to have a condition that causes them to not run during upgrades and repairs.  Have InstallServices run once during only the initial install and DeleteServices run only during a complete uninstall.  The downside to this is if you change any Service metadata it won't get applied.

Another possibility is to use a custom action to encrypt the credentials and write them to a file or registry key that only Administrators can read and then read them back in during subsequent installations.  (Re: WiX Remember Property Pattern)